# How to find a volume in Polar Coordinate System?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I asked Mathematica to do a very simple volume finding integration exercise for me. I tried on two different approaches, one on Cartesian and the other on Polar Coordinates, however, it gives me two different results. What is the correct way to do this problem on Polar Coord. System?
[image]

Comment: I guess you must ask it in the [$\texttt {http://mathematica.stackexchange.com}$ page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You polar parametrisation of the ellipse is correct but the bounds of integrations are wrong altogether with the order of integration. You have to integrate in $\theta$ last :

$\begin{cases}
x = rcos(\theta)\\
y= rsin(\theta)
\end{cases}$

Ellipse is given by $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

$\iff \frac{r^2cos(\theta)^2}{a^2}+\frac{r^2sin(\theta)^2}{b^2}=1\iff b^2cos(\theta)^2+a^2sin(\theta)^2=\frac{a^2b^2}{r^2}$

The polar parametrisation is $\displaystyle r(\theta)=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{b^2cos(\theta)^2+a^2sin(\theta)^2}}$

The integral becomes

$$I=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{ab}{\sqrt{b^2cos(\theta)^2+a^2sin(\theta)^2}}}\int_0^{mr\cos(\theta)}r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta=\frac 23 ma^2b$$

Comment: Hi zwim, you are right, thanks a lot!